# Why this python script doesn't work ? (Send cmd to SMTP serv)

Tags: python, security, scripting, network-programming

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Usage: vrfy.py <target> <file>"

s=socket.socket()
connect=s.connect((sys.argv[2],25))
banner=s.recv(1024)
print banner
with open(sys.argv[3],'r') as f:
        for name in f:
                s.send('VRFY ' + name)
                result=s.recv(1024)
                print result
s.close()
```

This is the error

```
root@nux:~# python vrfy.py 192.168.31.215 name.txt 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vrfy.py", line 12, in <module>
    connect=s.connect((sys.argv[2],25))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Why this script isn't working? It launch an exception immediately. 
The script is supposed to run "VRFY" with logins found in file.txt on a SMTP server
I'm not very familiar with python, I'm learning the hard way atm
Thank you

Comment: What exception? Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Add a `print sys.argv[2]` before the error line (basic debugging), and the problem will be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You  check the to make sure the  length of `sys.args` is equal to 3, but use `sys.argv[3]` which would be an index error, `indexes` start at `0`, so you would use `arg[1]` and `arg[2]` for the last of the three args.

Your `args[2]` and `args[3]` are not what you think they are.
You need to use `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`

You  also need an else or your program will crash if you don't have the correct args as the rest of your code is executed either way:

```
import socket
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Usage: vrfy.py <target> <file>"
        sys.exit(0)
else:        
    s=socket.socket()
    ...
```

Comment: Oops the identing was wrong here. But everything after the if shouldn't be idented and it still doesnt work. I edited my post